# Caching a url /file

Tags: php, caching, iframe, blocking

Am have no clue when it coming to Caching but I was running this file

```
<?php 
header('Location: http://stats.vbirc.com/remote.php?func=numinchan&param=%23animelon');
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```

My server got banned the firewall keep's blocking me automatically. I use this about code in a iframe for a custom image (it show's the user's in irc)

I want to be able to cache this so it's only hitting there servers once not everytime someone reloads a page etc...

Ok this some more detail

```
<a href="animelon.com/ezirc/" class="irctitle">#animelon irc.vbirc.org</a>
<br />Click the link above to join the official animelon chat room or join with you'er 
<a href="irc://irc.vbirc.org:6667/animelon">own client</a>. 
<span class="irc_usersonline"><strong><iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="22" height="16" scrolling="no" frameborder=0 src="irc_online.php">
</iframe>
</strong> people online</span>
</p>
</div>

animelon.com/irc_online.php
```

this is the name of the code I added at the start
this is where I want the cached info to show

img59.imageshack.us/img59/7931/ircz.jpg

(can't use image's so have to link to it)

Comment: To me your code does not really make sense: the header(Locacion) tells the browser, that the content is at another - the meta would make it  refresh the current page after some time. Could you be more specific about the context and what you are trying to do and which servers / pages are actually under your control.

Comment: Ive added somemore sorry and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of caching is pretty simple. An abstract example:

```
if((time() - $time_previously_fetched) > $expire_time){
  $contents = file_get_contents($url); //Retrieve from original source
  saveToDatabase($contents); //Cache it
  $time_previously_fetched = time(); //Save the time to check against for in future
}else{
  $contents = getFromDatabase(); //Retrieve local copy
}

echo $contents;
```

Comment: Actually I think you would rather want to make sure a 304 not modified is sent appropriately instead of delivering the content again and again.

Comment: I just figured out that the cached content is a single number and not a file/picture. A 304 does not make a difference in that case, so feel free to ignore my comment.

Comment: How can I use that code above than please? am not great at php also :/ Thanks alot for helping btw